# Create createQueryBuilder inside SQL query for TypeOrm

Tags: postgresql, typescript, typeorm

There is query that is dynamic built through createQueryBuilder, example query:

```
SELECT * FROM task
WHERE (("attrs"->>'count')::int > 300 ) 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

But me need next sql:

```
WITH tmp as (
SELECT * FROM task
WHERE (("attrs"->>'count')::int > 300 ) 
ORDER BY id DESC)
SELECT * FROM tmp LIMIT 100;
```

I know that in TypeOrm can add **LIMIT** in **qb.limit (100);** But need exactly for **WITH**. Is it possible create this through createQueryBuilder?

Comment: do you need to use the query builder?

Comment: yes,  query builder